# Binding a ControlTemplate's Button's Content and Command Parameter Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

Okay, this is probably something pretty simple that I'm not doing quite right. I am just now learning how to add items dynamically using an ItemsControl as shown below.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
                        <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                        <Button FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding SelectMaterialCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" Width="50" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click_2" Content="{Binding .Content}"></Button>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

The ItemsControl ItemsSource Property is bound to an ObservableCollection of Buttons. In code I can create a button, set the Content and CommandParameter properties and add it to the ObservableCollection. When I run the application a button is populated, but I can't get the Content and CommandParameter properties to bind correctly.

I have tried doing several different methods such as `Binding Path=.`, `Binding Path=Content`, `Binding Path=.Content`...etc, but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why didn't you use DataTemplate?

Comment: I am just learning this concept. Was I supposed to use a DataTemplate instead?

Comment: If you are expecting each item in the control to be button, then datatemplate is to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Subramaniam B's advice I got this to work by utilizing a Data Template as shown that is located in my UserControl.Resources section.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="temp" DataType="{x:Type local:ButtonModel}">
            <telerik:RadButton FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Content}" Width="100" Height="75" Margin="0,0,0,0" MouseLeftButtonUp="Button_Click_2" Content="{Binding Path=Content}">
                <telerik:RadButton.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="GhostWhite" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="GhostWhite" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </telerik:RadButton.Background>
            </telerik:RadButton>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Here is where the template is used were used:

```
<telerik:RadCarousel Loaded="MaterialCar_Loaded" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="MaterialCar" Height="200" Background="Blue"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource temp}" ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are setting the template for the whole ItemsControl (aka: LIST of buttons) to be A button.

No matter what items are in the Buttons collection, this control will render as a single button. Instead, you need to leave the template for the control itself alone, and use I template for the items that are IN the list.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
        <!-- ItemsControl.Template becomes ItemsControl.ItemTemplate below -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding SelectMaterialCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" Width="50" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click_2" Content="{Binding .Content}"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```